# What is Service Bus's equivalent to MSMQ's CanRead?

Tags: c#, azure, msmq, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am converting an application which used MSMQ to use an interface with adapters than can handle either MSMQ or Service Bus (either on-prem or Azure versions) queues.  One of the application's usages of MSMQ was a configuration inspector feature to determine that the system has proper privileges to perform certain actions.  It uses `System.Messaging.MessageQueue.CanRead` to verify that we can successfully read a given queue that is important to the application (it was a frequent security misconfiguration by customers).

The best equivalent in Service Bus is not apparent to me.  My first thought on an approach would be to attempt to `QueueClient.Peek()` and catch any ensuing exceptions.  The Peek method does not offer a timeout parameter, so I can only hope that this will happen quickly.  I would prefer to use a timeout so I can force it to return quickly in the likely scenario that there are currently no messages to read.  There is `Receive(TimeSpan serverWaitTime)` where I can pass in a tiny wait time, but I think that would require me to use a transaction and abort it if I do happen to receive a message.  That would lock up the queue when I would rather prefer not to.

I'm hoping there's a better option I have missed.

Comment: There's no such feature as of now.

Comment: When you create a receiver, you need to specify the connection string of the namespace + sas key. If you provide a sas key that does not allow read permission on the queue, you ll get an exception

Comment: @Thomas, this worked fine.  If you wanted to include it as answer, I will mark it accepted.  Sorry for such a late response.

Comment: No worries :-) I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `MessageReceiver`, you need to specify the connection string of the namespace + sas key. If you provide a sas key that does not allow read permission on the queue, you ll get an exception.